# Вопрос с запросом на обновление в Access

Tags: access

***Доброго времени суток!***

У меня 2 вопроса, правда один вытекает из другого.

**1 вопрос.**

Всего у меня три поля, нужно посчитать 4-ое, предварительно рассчитав второе (можно сделать статистическими данными, но лучше автоматизировать). Возможно ли это?

- 1 поле - Номер
- 2 поле - Этаж (1,2,3,4,5)
- 3 поле - Класс номера (стандарт, люкс, президент)
- 4 поле - Цена (1000 - заданное значение)

*У меня получилось сделать это через 15 запросов, и я сделал макрос, можно ли его автоматизировать, чтобы каждый раз при изменении таблицы не выдавал табличку: **"Разрешить изменения?"***

**2 вопрос.**

У меня получилось сделать через sql-код данные действия, но возможно во-первых сделать это в конструкторе и у меня получилось сделать через запрос - создание новой таблицы, а в старой у меня маски ввода, типы данных, чтобы все это не прописывать, можно код представленный ниже перестроить в запрос на обновление?

```
SELECT Номер, [Класс номера], Этаж, Телефон, Уборка, [Примечание], Цена INTO Номера
FROM (SELECT [Номер], [Класс номера], val(mid([Номер],2))\100 AS Этаж, IIf([Класс номера]="стандарт",1,IIf([Класс номера]="люкс",2,3)) AS klass, Телефон, Уборка, [Примечание], ccur((1000*klass+500*(Этаж-1))*[Места]) AS Цена FR OM База)  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

*Если кому нужно залил [файл](http://bon4.ru/loadings/test.rar), так как не получается добавить во вложения.*

**Заранее спасибо за ответ!**

Answer (score 1):

Макросы зло! Вместо них следует написать функцию на VBA, которая все, что нужно, посчитает.

Рекомендую глянуть в сторону книжки "Разработка настольных приложений в Access 2002".
http://msa.polarcom.ru/st/s0000262.htm